# Store RNN states using graph collections

Tags: tensorflow

I frequently use `tf.add_to_collection` to have Tensorflow automatically serialize intermediary results into a checkpoint. I find this the most convenient way to later fetch pointers to interesting tensors when a model was restored from a checkpoint. However, I realized that RNN state tuples cannot easily be added to a graph collection. Consider the following dummy example in TF 1.3:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


in_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 5, 1])
batch_size = tf.shape(in_)[0]

cell1 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=128)
cell2 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=256)
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell1, cell2])

outputs, last_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cell,
                                        inputs=in_,
                                        initial_state=cell.zero_state(batch_size, dtype=tf.float32))

tf.add_to_collection('states', last_state)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(in_ - outputs)
loss_s = tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('.', tf.get_default_graph())

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    l, s = sess.run([loss, loss_s], feed_dict={in_: np.ones([1, 5, 1])})
    writer.add_summary(s)
```

This will produce the following warning:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Error encountered when serializing states.
Type is unsupported, or the types of the items don't match field type in CollectionDef.
'tuple' object has no attribute 'name'
```

It seems that the serialization cannot handle tuples, and of course the `last_state` variable is a tuple. May be one could loop through the tuple and add each element individually to the collection, but that seems too complicated. What's a better way of handling this? In the end, I would like to access `last_state` again when the model is restored, ideally without needing access to the original code that created the model.

Comment: have you found the answer?

Comment: @neouyghur No, unfortunately not.

Comment: @neouyghur found a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, looping through every element of the state is not too complicated, and straight-forward to implement:

```
def add_to_collection_rnn_state(name, rnn_state):
    for layer in rnn_state:
        tf.add_to_collection(name, layer.c)
        tf.add_to_collection(name, layer.h)
```

And then to load it:

```
def get_collection_rnn_state(name):
    layers = []
    coll = tf.get_collection(name)
    for i in range(0, len(coll), 2):
        state = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple(coll[i], coll[i+1])
        layers.append(state)
    return tuple(layers)
```

Note that this assumes that one collection only stores on state, i.e. use a different collection for every state you want to store, e.g. like this:

```
add_to_collection_rnn_state('states', last_state)
add_to_collection_rnn_state('init_state', init_state)
```

**Edit**

As pointed out correctly in the comments, the proposed solution only works for LSTMCells (that are represented as tuples as well). A more general solution that can handle GRU cells or potentially custom cells and mixes thereof, could look like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def add_to_collection_rnn_state(name, rnn_state):
    # store the name of each cell type in a different collection
    coll_of_names = name + '__names__'
    for layer in rnn_state:
        n = layer.__class__.__name__
        tf.add_to_collection(coll_of_names, n)
        try:
            for l in layer:
                tf.add_to_collection(name, l)
        except TypeError:
            # layer is not iterable so just add it directly
            tf.add_to_collection(name, layer)


def get_collection_rnn_state(name):
    layers = []
    coll = tf.get_collection(name)
    coll_of_names = tf.get_collection(name + '__names__')
    idx = 0
    for n in coll_of_names:
        if 'LSTMStateTuple' in n:
            state = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple(coll[idx], coll[idx+1])
            idx += 2
        else:  # add more cell types here
            state = coll[idx]
            idx += 1
        layers.append(state)
    return tuple(layers)


in_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 5, 1])
batch_size = tf.shape(in_)[0]

cell1 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=128)
cell2 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(num_units=256)
cell3 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(num_units=256)
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell1, cell2, cell3])
outputs, last_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cell,
                                        inputs=in_,
                                        initial_state=cell.zero_state(batch_size, dtype=tf.float32))

add_to_collection_rnn_state('last_state', last_state)
last_state_r = get_collection_rnn_state('last_state')
```

Comparing `last_state` and `last_state_r` reveals that both are identical (which they should be). Note that I am using a different collection to store the names because tensorflow can only serialize a collection when all elements in the collection are of the same type. E.g. mixing strings with Tensors in the same collection does not work.

Comment: If you use a different RNN cell such as GRU, then your state object is not an instance of tuple as in the case of LSTM cell.

Comment: @eaksan You are right of course, thanks for your suggestion. Please see my edited answer.